# What does/does not belongs in WidgetProvider

Tags: android, widget

Widget Provider is a specialized BroadcastReceiver.

Assuming there exists an Application, 1-n  android service,1-k activities, and potentially additional 0-n broadcast receivers that are not widgets, I would like to verify what belongs and does not belong logically inside the broadcast receiver.  Here are some items ..

And assuming that generally what gets launched is the widget first.

Please comment on any of the items as to whether they belong inside or outside the widget and why.  Thanks.

1) If the application needs to always listen for certain events whether they show up in the widget or not where should this go?  In the Widget?  If not what would keep the broadcast receiver available to listen to the events for the application?

2) Should the widget issue notification? or request a service to issue them? ie should the notification logic reside in the widget itself or in the service.

3)  Should the widget issue broadcasts or ask a service to do this?

4)  Should the widget ever access any system services like like Notification Manager, PowerManager etc  Why, Why not?

5) Should the widget keep any of its own state?  If it should not keep state how can it change what it displays?  Like a different text or icon?

6) Should the widget start off activities or let a service handle this?

7) is it ok to user the context passed to update and receiver or should one use ctx.getApplicationContext() to do things like context.startService? ( Perhaps the one passed in is the application context ? )

Answer (score 1):

[Quoting myself](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_frm/thread/9419c15942bd6751) from your cross-post to the `android-developers` Google Group:

Your entire question is phrased around "the Widget". There is no "the 
Widget". From the opening sentence of your question, I am interpreting 
"the Widget" to mean "a subclass of `AppWidgetProvider` that handles the 
processing for an app widget or family of app widget instances".

> 1) If the Application needs to always listen for certain events 
>   whether they show up in the widget or not where should this go? In the 
>   Widget?

There is no reason for an `AppWidgetProvider` to respond to other 
broadcasts, since anything can update the app widget's `RemoteViews`. 
And an `AppWidgetProvider` cannot register listeners (e.g., 
`PhoneStateListener`). 
Hence, I would say the answer here is "no".

> 2) Should the widget issue notification? or request a service to issue 
>   them? ie should the notification logic reside in the widget itself or 
>   in the service.

Technically, AFAIK, raising a notification is cheap and therefore safe 
for an `AppWidgetProvider` to do. 
Logically, an `AppWidgetProvider` should never have any reason to raise 
a notification, IMHO.

> 3) Should the widget issue broadcasts or ask a service to do this?

Technically, AFAIK, sending a broadcast is cheap and therefore safe 
for an `AppWidgetProvider` to do. 
Logically, an `AppWidgetProvider` should never have any reason to send 
broadcasts, IMHO.

> 4) Should the widget ever access any system services like like 
>   Notification Manager, PowerManager etc Why, Why not?

This cannot be answered in the abstract.

> 5) Should the widget keep any of its own state? If it should not keep 
>   state how can it change what it displays? Like a different text or 
>   icon?

It may need to. For example, suppose you have an app widget that shows 
the weather for a certain city. The configuration activity for that 
app widget allows the user to choose the city. Somewhere, you need to 
store that city, and distinct from the cities that any other instance 
of that app widget may need (e.g., user adds two copies of the app 
widget to track weather in two cities).

> 6) Should the widget start off activities or let a service handle 
>   this?

An `AppWidgetProvider` should never have a reason to directly "start off 
activities", nor should a service triggered from an `AppWidgetProvider` 
have any reason to directly "start off activities", IMHO.

However, either are perfectly welcome to create `PendingIntents` that 
"start off activities" and attach them as click handlers for widgets 
in an app widget's `RemoteViews`.

> 7) is it ok to user the context passed to update and receiver or 
>   should one use ctx.getApplicationContext() to do things like 
>   context.startService? ( Perhaps the one passed in is the application 
>   context ? )

Most things you can just use the passed-in `Context`. One thing that 
will not work for is using `registerReceiver()` with a `null` receiver to 
get the last value of a sticky broadcast, such as 
`ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` -- for that, you will need to use 
`getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: Yes. I am referring to the WidgetProvider when using the term widget.

Comment: Could you clarify why an WidgetProvider should probably not need to issue broadcasts or directly start activities etc?

Comment: How long is the WidgetProvider guaranteed to be on the home screen listening to and responding to widgets.  Is there a setting that effects this?  In general its just not clear to me how long a broadcast receiver stays actively listening to Intent messages that its filtering on.  How does one guarantee that a WidgetReceiver or and Broadcast Receiver is ready to receive the intents for an extended period of time until Widget is removed?  how is this different for WidgetRecieves than other broadcast receivers?

Comment: I would add that sometimes I come to the Home screen and see that my widget has turned into the flat Toast message "Problem Loading Widget" it does not even say which one is effected.

Comment: I would also add there is no tag for Widget-Provider on this formum. So it is hard to target questions just to this topic

Comment: @Androider: "Could you clarify why an WidgetProvider should probably not need to issue broadcasts or directly start activities etc?" -- why would it? Do you often pop up activities in front of users when they do not request them?

Comment: @Androider: "How long is the WidgetProvider guaranteed to be on the home screen listening to and responding to widgets." -- the `AppWidgetProvider` is not "on the home screen".

Comment: @Androider: "In general its just not clear to me how long a broadcast receiver stays actively listening to Intent messages that its filtering on." -- an instance of a `BroadcastReceiver` that is registered in the manifest, like an `AppWidgetProvider`, lives for exactly one broadcast. The `BroadcastReceiver` class will be eligible to receive broadcasts so long as it is enabled, at least until the user uninstalls the app.

Comment: @Androider: "I would add that sometimes I come to the Home screen and see that my widget has turned into the flat Toast message "Problem Loading Widget" it does not even say which one is effected." -- your `AppWidgetProvider` failed to supply a valid `RemoteViews`, possibly because it crashed.

Comment: Ok. Last comment as I have posted this under a more specific question, although the broadcast receiver may technically be eligable to receive broadcasts so long as it is enabled, it certainly can and does go into states where it is essentially not responding, and the app is still running.  The fallen flat  cryptic toast message is a real eyesore and anything but informative. Hope there is a solution but thats another topic